# Ошибка линковки связанная с headers...

Tags: box2d, c++

Здравствуйте, помогите разобраться с такой вот ошибкой(ами):

> `1>LINK : warning LNK4098: defaultlib 'LIBCMT' conflicts with use of other libs; use /NODEFAULTLIB:library
> 1>App.obj : error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol "public: __thiscall b2World::~b2World(void)" (??1b2World@@QAE@XZ) referenced in function "void __cdecl OnTimer(void)" (?OnTimer@@YAXXZ)
> 1>App.obj : error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol "public: void __thiscall b2World::ClearForces(void)" (?ClearForces@b2World@@QAEXXZ) referenced in function "void __cdecl OnTimer(void)" (?OnTimer@@YAXXZ)
> 1>App.obj : error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol "public: void __thiscall b2World::Step(float,int,int)" (?Step@b2World@@QAEXMHH@Z) referenced in function "void __cdecl OnTimer(void)" (?OnTimer@@YAXXZ)
> 1>App.obj : error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol "public: class b2Fixture * __thiscall b2Body::CreateFixture(struct b2FixtureDef const *)" (?CreateFixture@b2Body@@QAEPAVb2Fixture@@PBUb2FixtureDef@@@Z) referenced in function "void __cdecl OnTimer(void)" (?OnTimer@@YAXXZ)`

Уже долго борюсь с этим... Единственное, что нашел в сети - это [этот сайт](http://www.box2d.org/forum/viewtopic.php?f=7&t=1502). Вроде как тут нашли решение этой проблемы, но я вообще не знаю английского. Можете растолковать, в чем проблема и что куда тыкать?

Спасибо.

Answer (score 1):

Вот тут на самом деле описана ваша проблема: [Ошибка LNK4098 на MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa267384(v=vs.60).aspx)

Пишут, что ошибка возникает, когда вы пытаетесь использовать разные версии одной и той же библиотеки времени выполнения (например, debug и non-debug, однопоточную и многопоточную).

Предлагают попробовать добавить ключ компоновщика /NODEFAULTLIB:libcmt.lib

Comment: А можете по подробнее описать как добавить? Cв-ва проекта, а куда дальше? Просто я не часто туда заглядываю...

Comment: Под рукой студии нет. На [страничке опции /NODEFAULTLIB в MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/3tz4da4a(v=vs.80).aspx) предлагают такой алгоритм:

1. Открыть диалог Property Pages
2. Кликнуть на Linker
3. Кликнуть на Input
4. Выбрать Ignore All Default Libraries или указать перечень библиотек в Ignore Specific Library (ваш вариант, указать игнорируемую библиотеку libcmt.lib)

После этого в свойстве Command Line должно появиться /NODEFAULTLIB:libcmt.lib

Если не поможет, надо дальше разбираться.

Comment: Вроде всё сделал, появилась другая ошибка:
error MSB4030: "libcmt.lib" is an invalid value for the "IgnoreAllDefaultLibraries" parameter of the "Link" task. The "IgnoreAllDefaultLibraries" parameter is of type "System.Boolean".

в Command Line нет строки /NODEFAULTLIB:libcmt.lib

Comment: Я написал выше: ваш вариант Ignore Specific Library (Ignore All Default Libraries не надо)

Comment: Есть ошибки... перед тем, как я применил к Ignore Specific Library, эту настройку выскочило сообщение "there are no property pages for the selection" и ошибки:

>`1> All outputs are up-to-date.
1>App.obj : error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol "public: __thiscall b2World::~b2World(void)" (??1b2World@@QAE@XZ) referenced in function "void __cdecl OnTimer(void)" (?OnTimer@@YAXXZ)
1>App.obj : error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol "public: void __thiscall b2World::ClearForces(void)" (?ClearForces@b2World@@QAEXXZ) referenced in function "void __cdecl OnTimer(void)" (?OnTimer@@YAXXZ)....`

Comment: По поводу этой ошибки есть [статья на MSDN на русском языке](http://msdn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/library/799kze2z.aspx)